# PHP Xpath with hebrew

Tags: php, xpath, hebrew

I'm having a trouble running XPath on some hebrew content.
My code:

```
$strGames = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><Array1 xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><Live><Name>שלום</Name><ID>11113</ID></Live></Array1>";
$Games = new SimpleXMLElement($strGames);
$live = $Games->xpath("/*[local-name()='Array1']/*[local-name()='Live' and contains(.,'שלום') and namespace-uri()='http://tempuri.org/']");
```

The '$live' variable contains an empty array after executing it.

If I'm executing with "contains(.,'11113')" - I'm geting the result - so the problem is 
definately in the hebrew part.

What can be the problem ?

Comment: hebrew isn't part of iso-8859-1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the encoding in your `$strGames` to UTF-8.

```
$strGames = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Array1 xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><Live><Name>שלום</Name><ID>11113</ID></Live></Array1>";
```

Also make sure your editor is set to read/write documents as UTF-8.

Hope this helps.